# Google Calendar API - recurring events instances are not fetched

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to fetch all events from a Google calendar using V3 API. I've noticed an issue regarding recurring events.
For some recurring events, on some calendars, only the first instances are fetched (for example - first 5 out of total of 8 instances are fetched).

Few additional details:

- I've double checked that the query date-range is correct.
- Problem occurred few times - for different Google Apps organizations.
- Problem occurs also if I try to fetch the events from the calendar of the event creator.
- We are using Google's python library for fetching.

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set the "singleEvents" flag to True when calling the the API's 'list' command.
From the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list):

> Whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the underlying recurring events themselves. Optional. The default is False.